# Eclipse TableViewer set custom row background

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, tableview, jface, tableviewer

How can a make my jface tableviewer display a chosen background color for specific rows?
I have a timestamp in each row and like to give a row thats timestamp is on a monday a color, different than the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ColumnLabelProvider it is even easier:

```
col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

@Override
public Color getBackground(final Object element) {
    if (element instanceof YourClass) {
        if (((YourClass) element).shouldBeRed()) {
            return new Color(Display.getDefault(), 0xFF, 0xDD, 0xDD);
        }
    }

    return super.getBackground(element);
}
```

});

Of course you should not create new colors on each getBackground but use resource managers for that purpose.

Comment: Exactly the solution I ended up with, too. Sorry for forgetting to post it.  Thanks :)

Comment: This is only setting the color of one column cell. I'm interested too in what the author asked: how can I set the color of a whole row depending on the value of one column cell? Do I really have to implement this for each column?

Comment: You could use a single LabelProvider for the whole table instead of having one for each row: table.setLabelProvider(...). You also could provide some base class for your ColumnLabelProviders that takes care of the getBackground method.

Comment: sadly the ColumnLabelProvider overrides the behavior of the ITableLabelProvider. when you set the color in the LabelProvider for the table, you must use the LabelProvider for the whole row, no distinction between the columns. if you use the ITableLabelProvider, there is this distinction, but then the colors will be set for the columnIndex instead...

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of:

```
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
      @Override
      public void update(final ViewerCell cell) {
          YourRowItemClass rowItem = (YourRowItemClass) cell.getElement();
          if (rowItem.isMonday()) {
              cell.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN)); 
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: So i have to do this for each of my columns? Is there no better way?

Comment: extend LabelProvider (maybe implementing IColorProvider) and attach to the tableviewer via setLabelProvider().